# Undefined control sequence (\chemmacros_load_module:n {nomenclature})

Tags: chemmacros

is there currently a problem with the `chemmacros` package? I've just come back to my thesis to make corrections but I'm getting this new random error when I hadn't seemingly changed anything since the last time I processed the document. I've fully updated MikTex console but I always get this error when I use `chemmacros`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.669 \chemmacros_load_module:n
{nomenclature}
```

This error occurs no matter which chapter I build and it always adds one page at the beginning of the document with only the word nomenclature.

In my document preamble I have:

```
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all}}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code that shows the issue?

Comment: Do you also load `ghsystem`? Then this is https://github.com/cgnieder/ghsystem/issues/13 and can be resolved by defining `\chemmacros_load_module:n` to do nothing but gobble its argument.

Comment: Thank you, this github.com/cgnieder/ghsystem/issues/13 solved it!

Answer (score 4):

The error most likely does come from `ghsystem` and can be reproduced by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the package [is not adapted to v6 of `chemmacros`, yet](https://github.com/cgnieder/ghsystem/issues/13). Until it is the error can be resolved by defining `\chemmacros_load_module:n` to simply gobble its argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

---

Unrelated, but since you mention having

```
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all}}
```

in your preamble: this should raise the following warning in your log:

```
Package chemmacros Warning: The module mechanism has changed with v6!
(chemmacros)                =========================================
(chemmacros)                * All modules have been integrated into 
(chemmacros)                the main package and thus are preloaded 
(chemmacros)                already (unless you have loaded 
(chemmacros)                `chemmacros' with the `minimal' option).
(chemmacros)                * The new default corresponds to the 
(chemmacros)                earlier setting `modules=all'.
```

This means with an up to date `chemmacros` (newer than 2022/01/16) you can simply drop loading any modules. `\usepackage{chemmacros}` should suffice.